# Can _score from different queries be compared?

Tags: elasticsearch

In my application, I issue multiple queries, each of which to a different index.  Then, I merge the results from these queries, and sort them using the `_score` attribute, in order to rank them according to their relavance.  But I wonder if this makes sense at all, since the results came from different queries?

I guess my question is: can `_score`s from different queries be compared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of issuing multiple queries , it would be a good idea to club them together in a single query.
You can use index query to do index specefic operation.

So something like

```
{
  "bool": {
    "should": [
      {
        "indices": {
          "indices": [
            "index1"
          ],
          "query": {
            "term": {
              "tag": "wow"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "indices": {
          "indices": [
            "index2"
          ],
          "query": {
            "term": {
              "name": "laptop"
            }
          }
        }
      }

    ]
  }
}
```

Once this is done , results would be sorted based on the _score. 
Hope that helps.